First order logics exercise
Here is the exercise:
theorem T5_1 {α : Type} {P Q : α -> Prop} :
  ((∀ x, P x) → ∃ x, Q x) → (∃ x, P x → Q x) := by
    intro H
    by_cases H1 : (∃ x, P x) -- Case analysis on the existence of x such that P x holds
    {
      
    }
    { 
      -- Case 2: There does NOT exist an x such that P x (i.e., ∀ x, ¬P x)
    }

I am stuck here. I tried do use ChatGPT, it gave me the by_cases, but the inner part was incorrect, and I couldn't understand it. Does anybody know, what to do here?

The first step is to prove the theorem on paper. Do you know how?

@AndrejBauer I'll try, will add the proof as soon as I do it.

It is not clear to me if you are after just hints or an actual (annotated maybe) solution.  --  Here is a little hint: yes by_cases (IIANM, we do need LEM: in fact not just LEM, but that comes later), but not on exists x, P x, which is neither one of the premises, nor any conclusion...

@JulioDiEgidio I solved it! Please, look at the answer. Can it be improved?

I am not terribly familiar with Lean, so someone else will have to tell you if your proof could be written somewhat better: but I can tell you that I have proved the theorem in Coq and my proof corresponds to yours pretty much 1-to-1.

This one worked, I used the excluded middle law upon (∀ x, P x).
theorem T5_1 {α : Type} {P Q : α -> Prop} :
  ((∀ x, P x) → ∃ x, Q x) → (∃ x, P x → Q x) := by
    intro H
    by_cases H1 : (∀ x, P x)
    . specialize H H1
      cases H with
      | intro x Hq => 
        exists x
        intro _
        exact Hq
    . rewrite [Classical.not_forall] at H1
      cases H1 with
      | intro x Hnp => 
        exists x
        intro Hp
        exact False.elim (Hnp Hp)

